# Return value from row if multiple conditions are true

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have the following dummy Df:

```
structure(list(lat = c(15.04166667, 15.125, 15.29166667, 15.375, 
15.04166667, 15.125, 15.20833333, 15.29166667, 15.375, 15.45833333, 
15.54166667, 14.95833333, 15.04166667, 15.125, 15.20833333, 15.29166667, 
15.375, 15.45833333, 15.54166667, 15.625, 15.70833333, 15.79166667, 
15.875, 16.54166667, 13.875, 14.875, 14.95833333), lon = c(48.95833333, 
48.95833333, 48.95833333, 48.95833333, 48.875, 48.875, 48.875, 
48.875, 48.875, 48.875, 48.875, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 
48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 
48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 48.79166667, 
48.70833333, 48.70833333, 48.70833333), Var1 = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), Var2 = c(29.76510459, 
6.480850609, 223.0983795, 203.8934788, 11.27195619, 65.76071468, 
194.8171225, 262.4171485, 171.163622, 240.1846431, 239.8467942, 
53.94738807, 49.07189175, 118.194278, 218.744134, 313.4466307, 
185.409121, 252.8829675, 219.123076, 211.2351477, 279.0554084, 
260.621935, 169.9482421, 337.1199379, 9.932910029, 96.11876075, 
69.54847552), Var3 = c(6.24087876, 1.358846252, 46.77725586, 
42.75054481, 2.363402045, 13.78811339, 40.84749728, 55.02126264, 
35.88804325, 50.35974897, 50.28891223, 12.29369073, 10.28895202, 
24.78191063, 45.86429711, 65.72066044, 38.87491352, 53.02222021, 
45.94375161, 44.28987901, 58.50982373, 54.64485812, 35.63321409, 
70.68427011, 1.731396537, 20.15331521, 14.58229774), Var4 = c(173.4664468, 
173.4706729, 173.4790964, 173.4833057, 173.4077614, 173.4117034, 
173.4156335, 173.4195758, 173.4235096, 173.4266725, 164.1875386, 
239.5356333, 173.3490717, 173.3527418, 173.3563883, 173.3600476, 
173.3637073, 173.3667678, 164.1276972, 164.1295668, 164.1308363, 
164.1321065, 164.1333879, 167.3271206, 150.2922712, 224.8818893, 
224.8852899), Var5 = c(19.62146524, 19.62146505, 19.62146589, 
19.62146616, 19.62146629, 19.62146473, 19.62146495, 19.62146552, 
19.62146614, 19.62146513, 16.76539618, 38.78913858, 19.62146615, 
19.62146541, 19.62146505, 19.62146575, 19.62146599, 19.62146573, 
16.76539594, 16.76539677, 16.7653963, 16.76539632, 16.76539658, 
17.25115902, 11.78819987, 34.82506079, 34.82506128), var6 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "High", class = "factor"), 
    var7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "HIGH RISK", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

What I want to do is create a new variable called var8 which return Var2 only if Var6 is "High" and Var7 is "HIGH RISK" otherwise return nothing. Note that var6 and var7 have other factor( e.g. Low, Medium, SAFE.. )which are not provided in the example.

I tried this, but it return TRUE or FALSE value, whereas I want the value from VAr 2 only in case it being TRUE and 0 in case it is FALSE.

```
  df<- df %>% 
        mutate( Area.HRH=Var6 =="High"  & 
        (Var7== "HIGH RISK"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `if_else()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Area.HRH = if_else(var6 =="High" & var7== "HIGH RISK", Var2, NULL))
```

You can easily change what you want the `FALSE` criteria to return. This will return zero instead of `NULL`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Area.HRH = if_else(var6 =="High" & var7== "HIGH RISK", Var2, 0))
```

Comment: OP says *"and 0 in case it is FALSE"*, recommend replacing `NULL` with `0`.

Comment: Yeah, but it also says this "otherwise return nothing". So I picked one. Thank you for the comment. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Adam. Thank you! what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in base `R` with a single `ifelse()` statement.

```
df$var8 <- ifelse(df[, "var6"] == "High" & df[, "var7"] == "HIGH RISK",
                  df[, "Var2"],
                  0)
```

Comment: `<-` *inside* `ifelse` won't work. Use `ifelse` is a function that returns a result---you need to assign the result. `df$var8 <- ifelse(..., df$Var2, 0)`. (Assigning inside is how this would work with `if(){}else{}`, but that's not vectorized, so `ifelse()` is better here.)

Comment: It's a lucky bug that it works---only because OP's sample data doesn't include any `FALSE` values. The `ifelse()` function first checks the condition, in the case of OP's sample data, the condition is always true, so `ifelse` ignores the `FALSE` argument and runs the `TRUE` argument, `df$var8 <- df[, "Var2"]`. This result is returned, and because the code includes the assignment, the assignment is made. However, if OP's data included a single item where the condition was not met, both `TRUE` and `FALSE` arguments are needed and will be run, in that order...

Comment: First `df$var8 <- df[, "Var2"]` and then `df$var8 <- 0`. `ifelse()` will put the results into a vector based on the condition argument and return the correct results (printed on the console because they are not assigned), but since *the results of `ifelse`* are not assigned, it will be as if you just ran those two assignment lines, first `df$var8 <- df$var2`, then `df$var8 <- 0` ---and if you look at `df` all the `var8` values will be 0.

Comment: See for yourself with a toy example: `df = data.frame(a = 1:3);
ifelse(df$a < 2, df$b <- 0, df$b <- 1);
df`